# BigCommerce conditional

Tags: conditional-statements, bigcommerce, blueprint

I want to create a conditional statement for a simple workflow in my BigCommerce store. I want to add a panel to the left of the page just below the menu. The panel would just be little snippets of reviews or advertising headers but are conditional depending on which page is active. For instance, if the browser shows the about us page, I want one thing and if on the FAQs page a different one. I may want to also show different things for different categories. Is this possible?

I use the blueprint themes. The current left navigation looks like this:

```
<div class="Left">
    <div class="shop-by" id="title">shop by</div>
        %%Panel.SideCategoryList%%
        %%Panel.ProductTagCloud%%
    </div>
```

etc . . .

Answer (score 1):

This best option to do this is something along the lines of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("about") > -1){
    $("#SideBrandsPanel").hide();
  }
});
</script>
```

Depending on how complex you want to make it, you could use a javascript switch statement. That all being said, the content will still load, so it isn't dynamically selecting what to include in the page, it is selectively making it visible on a page by page basis. This could impact the user experience either through javascript failure (not likely to happen, but potential point of failure), size of the page content (mobile data), etc.

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for but getting there. I just want to add a small include that I can switch depending on what page is loaded and maybe even what category is loaded.

For instance, if the main t-shirt category is loaded, I would add a customer testimony about those tees. If the Pro-Fit category is loaded, I would add a different testimony.